# 【Net-ERR_FAILED】What can cause Chrome to give an net::ERR_FAILED when Large number of requests occured by http2s?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

```
When I send many requests in parallel, the browser gets "net-error". Occasionally some requests fail. The log shows that sending the request header failed. How to deal with it?
```

[image]
[image]

none of requests fail.